# Can't see JSON response in JMeter View Results Tree

Tags: json, jmeter

I was wondering if someone could tell me why I can't see the json response from a request that is also of type json in the JMeter View Results Tree. I know that the response is there because I use a regular expression to extract data (I wrote the reg ex based on result returned in Firebug). So the data can be extracted from the json response it just doesn't display in View Result Tree. I can see the json response for another request for a different app I performance test with JMeter, but that particular request is an ajax request. not sure

Answer (score 2):

Add a sample writer and display content here.

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer

You will see the issue

Answer (score 0):

HI there any one who looks in this post for jmeter, you may be bit worried when you cant find answers in internet regarding how to log your response when you sent a request , here is the solution and simple as it is...

just add a line like below.

result.setResponseData("put any content here to be displayed as String.", "UTF-8");

and check your response will be cool as you done.